# How to restart vsphere web client service in java?

Tags: java, install4j, vsphere, vcenter

For some reason, I want to restart **vSphere web client** service with the help of **java/install4j**.

Can we restart this service from Java irrespective of whether vCenter is installed on **Windows or Linux (VCSA)**  machine?